# CentOS fs (or folder) snapshot without LVM

Tags: linux, centos, backup, snapshot

I do not have an LVM volume in my CentOS7 setup, since RAID1 on XFS with LVM on top = possibly sub-optimal performance ([as stated here, have a look at Andres719's comment](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/465835-linux-raid-1-or-lvm-mirror))

However, I want to take a snapshot of atleast my DB and data folders for backup.

Is there a way I can get a snapshot of the folders without LVM.

(I may use 'cp', but then my production server will take a performance hit. Also, DBs will have to remain closed while cp does its work on, say, a 500GB folder)

Comment: I guess you misunderstood that comment. The performance hint refers to doing RAID-1 on a single drive (which could be done with `mdadm` as well, no need for LVM to do this). But XFS can do snapshots on filesystem level so no need for LVM either.

Comment: @Hauke - could you please point me to an article or command used to get an XFS snapshot. I usually find LVM snapshot articles when I search online for 'XFS snapshot'

Comment: Sorry, I misread a headline (I do not use XFS myself). XFS seems not to offer snapshots yet.

Comment: To quote the article you linked `"how do I do X" and the answer will be "do you have LVM" and you'll say "I don't" and we will answer "why not, now you can't do X`. If you're concerned about performance, did you do any benchmarks before you ruled LVM out?

Comment: @Patrick - I didn't benchmark myself, but had a look at this -  https://serverfault.com/questions/518329/xfs-slow-performance-on-lvmed-raid-faster-when-raw-or-non-lvm

Comment: I have dificulties believing that. And even the answer seems to doubt the claimed effects. Something may have gone terribly wrong there. There is no reason why LVM should slow down a filesystem that much.

Comment: There is a lot of things wrong with that question. Such as using `hdparm` to test the filesystem, and the idea that LVM produced a >43% speed increase over bare disk. Bottom line, stop trusting problem reports, and comments as authoritative sources. Use well prepared benchmarks that match your use case, or do it yourself (and understand what it is your're doing if so).